# Custom LINQ Query in Lightswitch

Tags: visual-studio-lightswitch

I'm confused about the way LINQ works within PreprocessQuery. I've been troubleshooting a problem with a larger query for a custom search screen. The rest of the query seems to work except for one small part that I've finally isolated:

```
query = query.Where(i => i.IntValue == 100);
```

This returns no results, even though the database clearly has values that match.

However, the following does work:

```
query = query.Where(i => i.StringValue == "value");
```

There aren't any calculated fields involved, which I've seen issues with before. What am I missing?

Comment: your IntValue is probably nullable. try 
query = query.Where(i => i.IntValue.HasValue && I.IntValue.Value == 100);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this particular case, it turned out that I had remnants of a query that had been built using the Lightswitch query designer. Both queries can coexist and complement each other, but (as in this case) they can also interfere. After clearing out the query from the designer, my code-based query worked great.

For future reference, if you start off with a query in the designer, and decide to switch, you should remember to clean out the stuff in the designer. In the [Lightswitch forum post](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/lightswitch/thread/f2dcc15d-ef43-4224-8f7a-7784d9f2db14), Yann mentioned that he always defaults to building the query in code, which is probably a pretty good idea if you have anything more than the simples of queries.

Answer (score 0):

As I stated in my reply to your [question in the LightSwitch Forum](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/lightswitch/thread/f2dcc15d-ef43-4224-8f7a-7784d9f2db14), I use this type of comparison all the time in *PreProcessQuery* methods, so if the following scenarios have been checked, this error shouldn't be happening.

The property is:

1. Of type ***int*** (not *byte*, *short*, *long*, *string* etc)
2. Not *nullable*

One thing that didn't get suggested in your post to the forum (actually, I just checked the post, & this syntax **was** actually suggested, but I'll leave it here for others, in case they don't realize there are two syntaxes), is to give the "alternate syntax" a try.

```
query = from q in query 
        where q.IntValue == 100
        select q;
```

The syntax shouldn't make any difference, but then again, the error shouldn't be happening either.

Comment: Thanks for being on Stackoverflow as well Yann. I cross posted because not everybody keeps up with both forums.

Comment: I try to help where I can. I just suggest that if you do cross-post that you put a link to the other post, like you've done in your reply. To be honest, sometimes I'm halfway through replying & I think to myself "this sounds familiar, didn't I answer this question somewhere". I'm glad you found your solution.